# How can I set default values in Eve?

Tags: python, eve

In Eve, the Python REST API framework, is it possible to set default values in a schema?  How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possibile, just use the `default` schema setting. From the [documentation](http://python-eve.org/config#schema-definition):

> The default value for the field. When serving POST and PUT requests, missing fields will be assigned the configured default values.
>
> It works also for types dict and list. The latter is restricted and works only for lists with schemas (list with a random number of elements and each element being a dict)

```
schema = {
  # Simple default
  'title': {
    'type': 'string',
    'default': 'M.'
  },
  # Default in a dict
  'others': {
    'type': 'dict',
    'schema': {
      'code': {
        'type': 'integer',
        'default': 100
      }
    }
  },
  # Default in a list of dicts
  'mylist': {
    'type': 'list',
    'schema': {
      'type': 'dict',
      'schema': {
        'name': {'type': 'string'},
        'customer': {
          'type': 'boolean',
          'default': False
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Nicola! Don't know why I missed that.